# ¿Cómo mostrar dropdown-menu en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando por javascript que el elemento `#tab4primary` se muestre.

ya que cuando ejecuto cierta acción en el botón se regresa al inicio y yo quiero que se muestre donde se ha quedado es decir si ha ingresado en una pestaña que se quede ahí.

Lenguaje que estoy trabajando

> asp.net c#
>
> javascript

Estoy realizando esta función, pero no se realiza.

```
 $('#btnTrigger li').click(function (e) {
    $('#tab4primary').dropdown('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab" class="btnTrigger">Generar Reporte</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown active">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Gráfico Pastel<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#tab4primary" data-toggle="tab" class="GA">Gráfico por asesores</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#tab5primary" data-toggle="tab">Gráfico por observaciones</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Gráfico Lineal<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#tab2primary" data-toggle="tab">Gráfico Lineal por año</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1primary">
                                    <h3>Reporte</h3>
                                    <table class="table"> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicioReport" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafinReport" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btngenerarreportes" runat="server" Text="Generar Reporte" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btngenerarreportes_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4primary">
                                   <h3>Gráfico por asesores</h3>
                                   <table class="table">
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                           <th><asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicio" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                           <th>
                                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafin" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>
                                               <asp:Button ID="btngenerargraficoasesor" runat="server" Text="Generar Gráfico asesor" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btngenerargraficoasesor_Click" /></th>
                                       </tr>
                                   </table>
                                   <div id="GrafpastelAsesores">
                                       <asp:Literal ID="grafpastelasesor" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5primary">
                                    <h3>Gráfico por observaciones</h3>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicioGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafinGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Agencia :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboagenciaGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btngenerargraficoobservacion" runat="server" Text="Generar Gráfico Observaciones" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btngenerargraficoobservacion_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                     <div id="grafpastelobservaciones">
                                         <asp:Literal ID="grafpastelobservacionesp" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2primary">
                                    <h3>Gráfico Lineal</h3>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Año :</th>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboanio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="2">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerarLineal" runat="server" Text="Generar Reporte Lineal" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  OnClientClick="btngenerarreportelineal()" OnClick="btnGenerarLineal_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <div id="GrafLineal">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="GrafLinealDibujo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: En donde esta el `#btnTrigger`?

Comment: @alanfcm modifique mi pregunta ahi esta

Comment: @PieroDev por favor utiliza el code snippet-[mira aquí cómo usarlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430/78) para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El selector es incorrecto.  `btnTrigger` es una clase, no un id.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$('.btnTrigger').click(function (e) {
    $('.GA').click();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab" class="btnTrigger">Generar Reporte</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown active">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Gráfico Pastel<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#tab4primary" data-toggle="tab" class="GA">Gráfico por asesores</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#tab5primary" data-toggle="tab">Gráfico por observaciones</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Gráfico Lineal<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#tab2primary" data-toggle="tab">Gráfico Lineal por año</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1primary">
                                    <h3>Reporte</h3>
                                    <table class="table"> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicioReport" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafinReport" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btngenerarreportes" runat="server" Text="Generar Reporte" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btngenerarreportes_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4primary">
                                   <h3>Gráfico por asesores</h3>
                                   <table class="table">
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                           <th><asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicio" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                           <th>
                                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafin" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                           <th>
                                               <asp:Button ID="btngenerargraficoasesor" runat="server" Text="Generar Gráfico asesor" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btngenerargraficoasesor_Click" /></th>
                                       </tr>
                                   </table>
                                   <div id="GrafpastelAsesores">
                                       <asp:Literal ID="grafpastelasesor" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5primary">
                                    <h3>Gráfico por observaciones</h3>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Inicio :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechainicioGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Fecha Fin :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfechafinGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Agencia :</th>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboagenciaGO" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btngenerargraficoobservacion" runat="server" Text="Generar Gráfico Observaciones" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btngenerargraficoobservacion_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                     <div id="grafpastelobservaciones">
                                         <asp:Literal ID="grafpastelobservacionesp" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2primary">
                                    <h3>Gráfico Lineal</h3>
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Año :</th>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboanio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="2">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerarLineal" runat="server" Text="Generar Reporte Lineal" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  OnClientClick="btngenerarreportelineal()" OnClick="btnGenerarLineal_Click" /></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <div id="GrafLineal">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="GrafLinealDibujo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: @alancfm cuando hago algo osea presiono clic en el boton que hace algo se regresa al principio pero yo quiero que si ingrese a una pestaña se quede donde esta. no se si me dejo entender